# issue rounding decimals in a sum SQL

Tags: sql, sum, rounding

I have a problem with a query, the rounding only works in the first row, do you know why?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.articulo AS articulo
    ,b.NombreArticulo AS nom_art
    ,sum(a.uni_vta_caja) AS Unidades
    ,round(sum(a.imp_vta_caja_neto), 2) AS Venta
    ,substring(cast(a.fec_vta AS VARCHAR), 4, 2) AS mes
FROM ConsultaDWH.dbo.F_Venta_21606 a
INNER JOIN consultadwh.dbo.articulos b ON a.articulo = b.articulo
WHERE a.Articulo IN (
        '1031260'
        ,'1031209'
        )
GROUP BY a.articulo
    ,b.NombreArticulo
    ,substring(cast(a.fec_vta AS VARCHAR), 4, 2)
```

The result appears:

```
articulo  nom_art                                   Unidades  Venta                 mes
1031209   Enutre Supl Alim Botellin 237ml Vainilla  686.0     14137.73              06
1031260   Enutre Supl Alim Botellin 237ml Fresa     597.0     12329.799999999999    06
```

Look at the .73 and .9999999 etc.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  What is the datatype of `imp_vta_caja_neto`?  Can you provide sample data?

Comment: It's hard to tell which column is which in your result. Please add headers

Comment: Please also provide the header for the query result.

Comment: Try casting `Venta` as a Decimal(x,2).  You're probably running into the Float precision issue.

Comment: SQL server,  about imp_vta_caja_neto is (real, null)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Answer (score 3):

If you want 2 decimal places, you will need to use `CAST` instead of `ROUND`:

`CAST(SUM(a.imp_vta_caja_neto) AS DECIMAL (8,2))`

`ROUND` can be misleading because most of us naturally think `ROUND(123.123,1)` should output one decimal place, `123.1`  What it actually does is round to the precision of the first decimal place, `123.100`.  If you want an explicit number of decimal places in your output, using `CAST` as decimal to will achieve this.  `CAST(123.123 as decimal (8,1))` = `123.1`

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question, which is "Do you know why?"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, it worked properly. But as Tab said, what was the reason for that result?.

Comment: @user29 Always happy to help - I had to take care of something at work but I've added some explanation now.